# Setting up Jupyter lab for python scripts on a cloud provider as a beginner

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cloud, devops

I have python scripts for automated trading for currency and I want to deploy them by running on Jupter Lab on a cloud instance. I have no experience with cloud computing or linux, so I have been trying weeks to get into this cloud computing mania, but I found it very difficult to participate in it.

My goal is to set up a full-fledged Python infrastructure on a cloud instance from whichever provider so that I can run my trading bot on the cloud.

I want to set up a cloud instance on whichever provider that has the latest python
installation plus the typically needed scientific packages (such as NumPy and pandas and others) in combination with a password-protected and Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)-encrypted Jupyter
Lab server installation.

So far I have gotten no where. I am currently looking at the [digital ocean website](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorial_collections/how-to-set-up-jupyter-notebook-with-python) for setting jupter lab up but there are so many confusing terms.

What is Ubuntu or Debian? Is it like a sub-variant of Linux operating system? Why do I have only 2 options here? I use neither of the operating system, I use the windows operating system on my laptop and it is also where I developed my python script. Do I need a window server or something?

How can I do this? I tried a lot of tutorials but I just got more confused.

Comment: Ubuntu and Debian are popular OS's which are built on top of linux kernel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution

Comment: PythonAnywhere offers notebooks, but not JupyterLab. They already have the Python infrastructure set up for you so it eliminates a lot of the more general choices you are facing in **skalthoff's excellent** answer. The nice thing is though it is browser based so that you don't need to make an ssh tunnel to connect your local system to the Jupyter tech running on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your question raises several more about what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you just trying to run your script on cloud services?  Or do you want to schedule a server to spin up and execute your code?  Are you running a bot that trades for you?  These are just some initial questions after reading your post.

Regarding your specific question regarding Ubuntu and Debian, they are indeed Linux distributions which are popular option for servers.  You can set up a Windows server on AWS or another cloud provider, but Linux distributions being much more popular are going to have lots of documentation, articles, stackoverflow posts around a Linux based server.

If you just want to run a script on a cloud on demand, you would probably have a lot of success following Wayne's comment around PythonAnywhere or Google Colab.

If you want your own cloud server, I would suggest starting small and slow with a small or free tier EC2 instance by following a tutorial such as this https://dataschool.com/data-modeling-101/running-jupyter-notebook-on-an-ec2-server/ Alternatively, you could splurge for an AWS AMI which will have much more compute power and be configured.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem and the most suiteble solution to me is using docker container for jupyter notebooks. The instructions on how to install Docker can be found at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ There is ready to use Docker image `docker pull jupyter/datascience-notebook` for jupyter notebook python stack. The docker compose files und sone addional insruction you will fid  at https://github.com/stefanproell/jupyter-notebook-docker-compose/blob/master/README.md.